# Can't see floating IP within Virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, floating-ip

When we spin a VM in cloud based environment ( in my case , `open-stack`) , and assign it a floating ip to access it from outside , we can't see that IP with standard Linux commands for networking, inside the VM. Why ? How it works?

Answer (score 0):

Correction: you just want to set up a route to the VM on any machines that want to access the floating IPs.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples

Leaving the wrong/reverse answer (typically already configured to happen automatically):

The machine inside the container doesn't know about the public network unless it has has been configured to see that via a bridge.

http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/compute-networking-nova.html

"Currently, Compute with nova-network only supports Linux bridge networking that allows virtual interfaces to connect to the outside network through the physical interface."

I'll refer you to that page for information on how to configure that.

Comment: the machine inside the container? or hypervisor?

Comment: Sorry, I answered the opposite of your question. I've corrected the answer to say you just want to set up a route to the private IP addresses assigned by the VM. You should be able to do this as long as you don't have address conflicts. But this is a networking issue, not a VM one.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples